# How do I fix 8-bit bytestrings error?

Tags: javascript, python, json, sqlite, web

I am working on a web application that parse multiple text files, store the data in a SQLite3 database and display the data in a browser. Then I make a HTTP request to my Node.js server to query the database. The data is converted to JSON and send back to the browser. Finally, the JSON is converted back to string and parse it for display.

My program works for small files size under 200MB, but very slowly in terms of parsing and displaying. When it gets 300MB+, I can not parse the files and got this error.

> ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
>   text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory =
>   str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your
>   application to Unicode strings.

I tried the text_factory, it gets rid of the error code. When I query the database, it returns nothing and the program hangs in there. I am a newbie. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make it parse larger size files and faster?

```
#parsing some files and insert them into a sqlite database 
#create database in python
conn = sqlite3.connect('MyDB.db') 
conn.text_factory = str # didn't work, the program hang
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE actions (dates text, names text, methods text)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE people (names text, ID text)''')

# insert in different function
dataB.execute("INSERT INTO people VALUES(?, ?)", (value[index], id))
dataB.execute("INSERT INTO action VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (date, value[index], someaction ))



//seperate file 
//retrieve the data from javascript

var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
var logDB = new sqlite3.Database("log.db"); 
query = "SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM people p, action a where p.name = a.name and p.id Not IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM someothertable);";


function queryTheServer(query, response) {

     logDB.all(query, function(error, thing){
                serveFromDatabase(error, thing, query, response);
            });
}

 //pass by as JSON
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
response.end();
```

Comment: I think I fix the parsing part. I did f = codecs.open(fs, encoding='utf-8'). to read in the files. My next questions is how do I make it faster.